# Changing wordpress version on AWS Lightsail

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

Looking for solutions to change the wordpress version on an Amazon A.W.S lightsail instance. I need to downgrade my wordpress version, If there is any other way to solve this, kindly suggest....

Comment: Welcome to [so] please see [ask]

Comment: Lightsail instances are virtual private servers over which you have full administrative access and control.  There is essentially nothing about the question that is specific to Lightsail, or AWS.  Assuming you're using the stock Bitnami image, you'll want to google for something like `downgrade wordpress version bitnami`.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Lightsail offers a small range of **pre-configured disk images, one of which is currently WordPress 4.8.0.

If none of the pre-configured AMIs meet your requirement, you can select an **OS-Only** image (eg Amazon Linux or Ubuntu) and **install WordPress yourself**.